# Combobox Examples

Tags: c#

I am getting the following error for foreach

Foreach statement cannot operate on variables of type 'object' because 'object' does not contain a public definition for 'GetEnumerator'

I am making any syntax error

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication6
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Namepopu_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            // this.textBox1.Text = Namepopu.Text;
           // this.textBox1.Text = " ";

            foreach (int i in Namepopu.SelectedItem)
                this.textBox1.Text += Namepopu.Text[i];
            {

            }
        }
        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You can't loop through a `SelectedItem`. What are you trying to do exactly?

Comment: Your braces are in the wrong place.

Answer (score 5):

Perhaps you meant to do this?

```
for (int i = 0; i < Namepopu.Items.Count; ++i)
{
    this.textBox1.Text += Namepopu.Items[i].ToString();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What's the contents of Namepopu.SelectedItem ? An array ? A generic list ? Cast it to it's original type first, then iterate over it in your foreach.

For example:

```
List<int> myValues = (List<int>)Namepopu.SelectedItem;

foreach (int i in myValues)
{
  ...
}
```

or

```
int[] myValues = (int[])Namepopu.SelectedItem;

foreach (int i in myValues)
{
  ...
}
```

Comment: If that's what the OP is going for, she can just use `IEnumerable<int>` in either case.

Answer (score 0):

```
textBox1.Text = string.Empty;
foreach (var item in Namepopu.SelectedItems)
   textBox1.Text += item.ToString();
```

Comment: `SelectedItems` is not a property of `ComboBox`.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are trying to get the enumerator for something that does not implement the IEnumerator interface. For a listing of the collection types you can iterate using a for each this MSDN article is useful (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dscyy5s0.aspx).