# combobox with for each loop

Tags: c#, winforms, datareader

Hi I am a student do anybody know after populating the combobox with the database values. How to display the same value in the text box.   When I select a name in the combobox  the same name should be displayed in the text box I am using seleted item.  Here is the code.

I am getting the error the following error using the foreach loop

foreach statement cannot operate on variables of type 'object' because 'object' does not contain a public definition for 'GetEnumerator'

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Data.OleDb;

namespace DBExample
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        private OleDbConnection dbConn; // Connectionn object
        private OleDbCommand dbCmd;     // Command object
        private OleDbDataReader dbReader;// Data Reader object
        private Member aMember;
        private string sConnection;
        // private TextBox tb1;
        // private TextBox tb2;

        private string sql;
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                // Construct an object of the OleDbConnection 
                // class to store the connection string 
                // representing the type of data provider 
                // (database) and the source (actual db)
                sConnection =
                    "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;" +
                    "Data Source=c:member.mdb";
                dbConn = new OleDbConnection(sConnection);
                dbConn.Open();

                // Construct an object of the OleDbCommand 
                // class to hold the SQL query. Tie the  
                // OleDbCommand object to the OleDbConnection
                // object
                sql = "Select * From memberTable Order " +
                      "By LastName , FirstName ";
                dbCmd = new OleDbCommand();
                dbCmd.CommandText = sql;
                dbCmd.Connection = dbConn;

                // Create a dbReader object 
                dbReader = dbCmd.ExecuteReader();

                while (dbReader.Read())
                {
                    aMember = new Member
                            (dbReader["FirstName"].ToString(),
                             dbReader["LastName"].ToString(),
                             dbReader["StudentId"].ToString(),
                             dbReader["PhoneNumber"].ToString());

                    // tb1.Text = dbReader["FirstName"].ToString();
                    // tb2.Text = dbReader["LastName"].ToString();

                    // tb1.Text = aMember.X().ToString();


                    //tb2.Text = aMember.Y(aMember.ID).ToString();  

                    this.comboBox1.Items.Add(aMember.FirstName.ToString());

                    // this.listBox1.Items.Add(aMember.ToString());
                    // MessageBox.Show(aMember.ToString());
                    // Console.WriteLine(aMember.ToString());
                }
                dbReader.Close();
                dbConn.Close();
            }

            catch (System.Exception exc)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("show" + exc);
            }
        }
        private void DbGUI_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }


        private void comboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            this.textBox1.Text = comboBox1.SelectedItem.ToString();

            textBox2.Text = string.Empty;
            foreach (var item in comboBox1.SelectedItem)
                textBox2.Text += item.ToString();
        }


        private void textBox2_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }
    }






}
```

Comment: Your loop doesn't make sense.  When you write code, you should understand what you're trying to accomplish and how the code will accomplish it.

Comment: Can you fix the formatting of the code?  Some of the code isn't being formatted.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5060300/combobox-examples

Comment: If your goal is to just to have the combobox display the text of the selected item, it will do that for you automatically. You don't need your SelectedIndexChanged handler.

Answer (score 4):

You just need to change the foreach loop to:

```
private void comboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            this.textBox1.Text = comboBox1.SelectedItem.ToString();

            textBox2.Text = string.Empty;
            foreach (var item in comboBox1.Items)
                textBox2.Text += item.ToString();
        }
```

Answer (score 2):

the above foreach(var item in comboBox1.Items)
item.ToString() just returns the system type

the below example worked for me to find the one I needed

```
foreach(DataRowView item in cmbUser.Items)
{
    if(item.Row[0].ToString() == "something")\\gets value displayed
    {
        //do something
    }
}
```